# how orientdb find the appropriate master node when queries come and how to know data is latest?

Tags: orientdb

When client issues a query, how does orientdb decide which master to choose ? If it chooses local master, what if the data in the local master is not latest, that is, syncing from other master is not complete when the query comes. Should the client retry later ?

Furthormore, if the same record is written at different places concurrently, how to determine the final data ? According to LWW (last write win) or something else strategy ?

Answer (score 0):

The OrientDB documentation already explained the solutions to this topic, you should look into these two pages (3.0.x):

- [Concurrency](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/general/Concurrency.html)
- [Replication](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/distributed/Replication.html)